# getting next() and prev() array elements not working as expected

Tags: php, arrays, pointers

I have an array with all the results of a query search.

My problem is that i need to select one row from this array, and then be able to select the next and previous row.

here is my code

```
function getUserProf(array $data, $faceid)
{
    //make sure that all data is saved in an array
    $userprof = array();

    //makes the array with the info we need
    foreach ($data as $val)
        if ($val['faceid'] == $faceid){
            $userprof = array ("id" => $val["id"], "total" => $val["total"], "faceid" => $val["faceid"], "lname" => $val["lname"], "fname" => $val["fname"], "hand" => $val["hand"], "shot1" => $val["shot1"], "shot1" => $val["shot1"], "shot2" => $val["shot2"], "shot3" => $val["shot3"], "shot4" => $val["shot4"], "shot5" => $val["shot5"]);
        }
        $next = next($data);//to get the next profile
        $prev = prev($data);//to get the next profile
        $userprofinfo = array('userprof' => $userprof, 'next' => $next);//make a array with the profile and the next prof and the prev prof

    //we return an array with the info
    return $userprofinfo;
}
```

This works somehow, but it doesn't give me the correct next and previous row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `prev()` moves the array pointer -1 and `next()` moves it +1 again, resulting in `$next` being the exact same row as the current one where you started before invoking `prev()`.

Also, you get `$prev` and `$next` after the complete `foreach()` run, which leaves the array pointer at the end of the array. (so you will always get the last element)

Try this instead:

```
function getUserProf(array $data, $faceid) {
    foreach ($data as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['faceid'] == $faceid) {
            return array( 
                'userprof' => $val,
                'prev'     => isset($data[$key-1]) ? $data[$key-1] : array(),
                'next'     => isset($data[$key+1]) ? $data[$key+1] : array()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @YairVillar for better performance, you could do this in SQL and return only the three desired profiles instead of returning *all* profiles to the application. (which is just overhead and will not scale well when you have 1000+ users)

Comment: yeah but these is for a competition of golf, so is gonna be max 100 people not more than that is a facebook app with a ipad form